# Is it possible to extract data from published Tableau workbook / server using python

Tags: python, pandas, sdk, tableau-api

As in title, any way to read data to a Pandas DataFrame?

Can't find much info about it anywhere. Found something about Tableau Data Extract and their SDK, but the first one doesn't seem to apply and can't find documentation for the latter.

Anyone can point me into the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options I am aware of:

1. [Tabcmd](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/tabcmd.htm)

Download the data as csv then load it in to a pandas data frame.You can use the subprocess module to run tabcmd from python.

Eg: `tabcmd export  "Sales_Workbook" --csv -f "output.csv" -s http://tabserver.mycompany.com -u admin -p mypassword -t your_sitename`

2. [Tableau REST API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref.htm#Query_View_Data)

Eg: `GET /api/api-version/sites/site-id/views/view-id/data?vf_<fieldname>=filter-value`